# MATLAB windowed FFT for a 2D matrix data (image)

Tags: matlab, image-processing, fft, windowed

Data:  Say I have a 2000 rows by 500 column matrix (image)

What I need:  Compute the FFT of 64 rows by 10 column chunks of above data. In other words, I want to compute the FFT of 64X10 window that is run across the entire data matrix. The FFT result is used to compute a scalar value (say peak amplitude frequency) which is used to create a new "FFT value" image.

Now, I need the final FFT image to be the same size as the original data (2000 X 500).

What is the fastest way to accomplish this in MATLAB? I am currently using for loops which is relatively slow. Also I use interpolation to size up the final image to the original data size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @EitanT pointed out, you can use `blockproc` for batch block processing of an image `J.` However you should define your function handle as

```
fun = @(block_struct) fft2(block_struct.data);
B = blockproc(J, [64 10], fun);
```

For a `[2000 x 500]` matrix this will give you a `[2000 x 500]` output of complex Fourier values, evaluated at sub-sampled pixel locations with a local support (size of the input to FFT) of `[64 x 10]`. Now, to replace those values with a single, e.g. with the peak log-magnitude, you can further specify

```
fun = @(block_struct) max(max(log(abs(fft2(block_struct.data)))));
B = blockproc(J, [64 10], fun);
```

The output then is a [2000/64 x 500/10] output of block-patch values, which you can resize by nearest-neighbor interpolation (or something else for smoother versions) to the desired [2000 x 500] original size

```
C = imresize(B, [2000 500], 'nearest');
```

I can include a real image example if it will further help.

**Update:** To get overlapping blocks you can use the `'Bordersize'` option of `blockproc` by setting the overlap `[V H]` such that the final windows of size `[M + 2*V, N + 2*H]` will still be [64, 10] in size. Example:

```
fun = @(block_struct) log(abs(fft2(block_struct.data)));
V = 16; H = 3; % overlap values
overlap = [V H]; 
M = 32; N = 4; % non-overlapping values
B1 = blockproc(J, [M N], fun, 'BorderSize', overlap); % final windows are 64 x 10
```

However, this will work with keeping the full Fourier response, not the single-value version with `max(max())` above.

See also this post for filtering using `blockproc:`[Dealing with “Really Big” Images: Block Processing](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2011/08/16/dealing-with-really-big-images-block-processing/).

Comment: What is the point of `block_struct.data`? Why do you assume it is stored in this way?

Comment: quoting from http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/ref/blockproc.html "A block struct is a MATLAB structure that contains the block data as well as other information about the block." You can check the examples also. In R2012a a handle such as @fft will not work, input should be struct. The function handle to `blockproc` should be "a function that accepts a block struct as input and returns a matrix, vector, or scalar."

Comment: Interesting. I thought `blockproc` behaved just like the (now obsolete) `blkproc`... thanks for pointing that out then. I'd better correct my answer too.

Comment: no problem, I was under the impression that it worked by default through @fun also.

Comment: Thank you for the response gevang and EitanT. Is there a way for the blocks to overlap? I don't understand how filter2 can be used. Thanks!

Comment: See the Update in my answer for a simple way to get overlapping windows, thus smoother boundaries between the FFT patches.

Comment: Unfortunately, `blockproc` doesn't "slide" the window, it just `inflates` the blocks' borderes so that they overlap, _but their amount remains the same_. I'm not sure that was the OP's original intention.

Comment: @EitanT true. What do you mean by "their amount" though? Note that you can change the sliding parameter through the final window length, i.e. you have 2 parameters final length and overlap amount. These can be translated to window center and window length and this way emulate a sliding window effect.

Comment: For this purpose I believe `blockproc` would be significantly slow. I suggest using `colfilt` then, which does not perform unnecessary padding. Please see my answer for reference.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to apply the same function (in your case, the 2-D Fourier transform) on individual distinct blocks in a larger matrix, you can do that with the [`blkproc`](http://www.weizmann.ac.il/matlab/toolbox/images/blkproc.html) function, which is replaced in newer MATLAB releases by [`blockproc`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/ref/blockproc.html).

However, I infer that you wish to apply apply `fft2` on overlapping blocks in a "sliding window" fashion. For this purpose you can use [`colfilt`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/colfilt.html) with the `'sliding'` option. Note that the function that we're applying on each block is the fft:

```
block_size = [64, 10];
temp_size = 5 * block_size;
col_func = @(x)cellfun(@(y)max(max(abs(fft2(y)))), num2cell(x, 1), 'Un', 0);
B = colfilt(A, block_size, 10 * block_size, 'sliding', col_func);
```

How does this work? `colfilt` processes the matrix `A` by rearranging each "sliding" block into a separate column of a new temporary matrix, and then applying the `col_func` to this new matrix. `col_func` in turn restores each column into the original block and applies `fft2` on it, returning the largest amplitude value for each column.

Important things to note:

1. Since this mentioned temporary matrix includes all possible "sliding" blocks, memory could be a limitation. Therefore, in order to use less memory in calculations, `colfilt` breaks up the original matrix `A` into sub-matrices of `temp_size`, and performs calculations separately on each. The resulting matrix B is still the same, of course.
2. Each element in the resulting matrix `B` is computed from the corresponding block neighborhood. The larger your image is, the more blocks you will need to process, so the computation time will increase geometrically. I believe that you'll have to wait quite a bit until MATLAB finishes processing *all* sliding windows on your 2000-by-500 matrix.

Comment: Thanks for the response EitanT!

Comment: I am having trouble with colfilt. I get the error: "Attempt to reference field of non-structure array." The same function works well with blockproc. Not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Does your function use the `block_struct.data`? Unlike `blockproc`, `colfilt` does not need a _block_struct_. Define your function like I did, and I believe it should work.

Comment: The function that I have written requires the input data to be 64 X 10. Colfilt seems to change it to a column during the first process and then in to a matrix. And yes, I am not using the struct format as you suggest.

Comment: Yes, it seems that `func` is expected to treat each column of its input as an individual block. I need to wrap my head around it a bit and revise `func`.

Comment: Okay, I think it works now, but the processing now takes time because of all the "sliding" blocks that need to be processed.

Comment: Thanks. The code works but it is 2 orders of magnitude slower than the 'for' loops I had in place!

Comment: Does it produce the same results?

Comment: Yes. I ran it on a small test image. I am going to have to use blockproc as suggested by gevang. Thanks

Comment: No problem. Maybe I'll find a workaround, but use what works best for you